# Mongoose populate either ObjectId reference or String

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Is there a way to specify a heterogeneous array as a schema property where it can contain both ObjectIds and strings? I'd like to have something like the following:

```
var GameSchema = new mongoose.schema({
    players: {
        type: [<UserModel reference|IP address/socket ID/what have you>]
    }
```

Is the only option a `Mixed` type that I manage myself? I've run across [discriminators](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html), which look somewhat promising, but it looks like it only works for subdocuments and not references to other schemas. Of course, I could just have a `UserModel` reference and create a `UserModel` that just stores the IP address or whatever I'm using to identify them, but that seems like it could quickly get hugely out of control in terms of space (having a model for every IP I come across sounds bad).

EDIT:

Example:

A game has one logged in user, three anonymous users, the document should look something like this:

```
{ players: [ ObjectId("5fd88ea85...."), "192.0.0.1", "192.1.1.1", "192.2.2.1"] }
```

Ideally this would be populated to:

```
{ players: [ UserModel(id: ..., name: ...),  "192.0.0.1", "192.1.1.1", "192.2.2.1"] }
```

EDIT:

I've decided to go a different route: instead of mixing types, I'm differentiating with different properties. Something like this:

```
players: [
    {
        user: <object reference>,
        sessionID: <string>,
        color: {
           type: String
        },
        ...other properties...
    }
]
```

I have a validator that ensures only one of `user` or `sessionID` are populated for a given entry. In some ways this is more complex, but it does obviate the need to do this kind of conditional populating and figuring out what type each entry is when iterating over them. I haven't tried any of the answers, but they look promising.

Comment: What do you want to use this for? That actually has importance as it depends on what you intend to do. Since you mention `ObjectId` then it would suggest you want to refer to an item in another/same collection. If you mix types, then things like `.populate()` will not work.

Comment: My goal is to allow either logged in users or anonymous users to join a game. Logged in users should have the game associated with their login, anonymous users (obviously) don't have a login. `populate()` is one of the things I wasn't sure about; if my use case were supported by Mongoose, then presumably there would be a way for it to smartly `populate` only those entries in the array that are ObjectIds, but you're saying that won't happen?

Comment: Yes I am saying that will not happen. Instead of trying to explain in comments, take the time and expand on your use case ( preferably with example data and desired outcomes ) in your question. A good way to a question is to **not** phrase it in terms of what *"you think the solution is"*, but rather to simply explain the problem in terms of the eventual result you want. These points could be clearer in order to give the best advice,

Comment: You could use the [mongoose-ajv-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-ajv-plugin) and use JSON schema (implemented by the [AJV library](http://epoberezkin.github.io/ajv/)) for object validation.  That would allow you to validate the array, but would not magically let you `populate` it. 
 Disclaimer: I'm the author of the plugin.

Comment: @Jthorpe That would appear to help with issues around "Mixed" types, but unless I'm missing something there does not appear to be anything there which would aid in using `.populate()` where the data was either a referenced `ObjectId` or an un-related "string", which is the main intent if I am reading correctly. If you had example of where this applied to `.populate()` then I think this would be a useful sample. AFAIK `.populate()` blows up on this, but MongoDB can do this "join" itself with a little wrangling.

Comment: @NeilLunn Yep, you got it. My comment only addressed validation of the mixed type array, which was only a minor part of the question asked.

Comment: Is there something not addressed in the answer that is vital to the question? There is a working example there but there has been no feedback from you.

Comment: @NeilLunn No; I haven't personally tried out the solution (as mentioned in my edited post, I went a different route) so I don't know that I should necessarily mark it as the answer. Not sure about the SO etiquette here...

Comment: As for etiquette then i would suggest you consider that a solution was provided before you made a change in direction and edited the post, and that you were given a great deal of feedback on the issues to face. As such you should consider the answer given and should it answer your essential question at the time asked being *"How can I populate a Mixed List of Reference and String?"* , and when the answer shows it achieves that goal then you mark it as correct. That is what people view the question for. Does the answer do what the question asks? Well there is a test case and results there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are content to go with using `Mixed` or at least some scheme that will not work with `.populate()` then you can shift the "join" responsibility to the "server" instead using the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) functionality of MongoDB and a little fancy matching.

For me if I have a `"games"` collection document like this:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5933723c886d193061b99459"),
        "players" : [
                ObjectId("5933723c886d193061b99458"),
                "10.1.1.1",
                "10.1.1.2"
        ],
        "__v" : 0
}
```

Then I send the statement to the server to "join" with the `"users"` collection data where an `ObjectId` is present like this:

```
Game.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "users": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$players",
        "as": "p",
        "cond": { "$gt": [ "$$p", {} ] }
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "users",
    "localField": "users",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "users"
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "players": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$players",
        "as": "p",
        "in": {
          "$cond": {
            "if": { "$gt": [ "$$p", {} ] },
            "then": {
              "$arrayElemAt": [
                { "$filter": {
                  "input": "$users",
                  "as": "u",
                  "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$u._id", "$$p" ] }
                }},
                0
              ]
            },
            "else": "$$p"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Which gives the result when joined to the users object as:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5933723c886d193061b99459"),
        "players" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5933723c886d193061b99458"),
                        "name" : "Bill",
                        "__v" : 0
                },
                "10.1.1.1",
                "10.1.1.2"
        ]
}
```

So the "fancy" part really relies on this logical statement when considering the entries in the `"players"` array:

```
  "$filter": {
    "input": "$players",
    "as": "p",
    "cond": { "$gt": [ "$$p", {} ] }
  }
```

How this works is that to MongoDB, an `ObjectId` and actually all BSON types have a [specific sort precedence](http://docs.mongoing.com/manual-zh/reference/bson-type-comparison-order.html). In this case where the data is "Mixed" between `ObjectId` and `String` then  the "string" values are considered "less than" the value of a "BSON Object", and the `ObjectId` values are "greater than".

This allows you to separate the `ObjectId` values from the source array into their own list. Given that list, you [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to perform the "join" at get the objects from the other collection.

In order to put them back, I'm using `$map` to "transpose" each element of the original `"players"` where the matched `ObjectId` was found with the related object. An alternate approach would be to "split" the two types, do the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) and [`$concatArrays`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/) between the `Users` and the "strings". But that would not maintain the original array order, so [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) may be a better fit.

---

I will add of note that the same basic process can be applied in a "client" operation by similarly filtering the content of the `"players"` array to contain just the `ObjectId` values and then calling the "model" form of [`.populate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.populate) from "inside" the response of the initial query. The documentation shows an example of that form of usage, as do some answers on this site before it was possible to do a "nested populate" with mongoose.

The other point of mind here is that `.populate()` itself existed as a mongoose method long before the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) aggregation pipeline operator came about, and was a solution for a time when MongoDB itself was incapable of performing a "join" of any sort. So the operations are indeed "client" side as an emulation and really only perform additional queries that you do not need to be aware of in issuing the statements yourself.

Therefore it should generally be desirable in a modern scenario to use the "server" features, and avoid the overhead involved with multiple queries in order to get the result.