# Mongoose populate by email

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

On the backend I have two Schemas:

User:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    isActive: {type: Boolean, default: false},
    isVerified: {type: Boolean, default: false},
    firstName: {type: String, required: [true, "can't be blank"]},
    lastName: {type: String, required: [true, "can't be blank"]},
    email: {type: String, lowercase: true, unique: true, required: [true, "can't be blank"], match: [/\S+@\S+\.\S+/, 'is invalid'], index: true},
    phone: {type: Number, unique: true, required: true, required: [true, "can't be blank"]}, // validate phone
    role: {type: String, enum: ['invalid', 'precustomer', 'customer', 'broker', 'brokerAdmin', 'dealer']},
    hash: String,
    salt: String,
    address: {type: Object, required: [isRequired('address'), "can't be blank"]}, //require customer
    organization: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Organization',
        required: [isRequired('organization'), "can't be blank"]}, //require broker && dealer
    deliverySchedule: String // for now.. make this custom obj soon --- OPTIONAL
}, {timestamps: true});
```

Application:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');

var ApplicationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    customer: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: [true, "can't be blank"]},
    dealer: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: [true, "can't be blank"]},
    broker: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: [true, "can't be blank"]},
    files: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Files', required: [true, "can't be blank"]},

}, {timestamps: true});

mongoose.model('Application', ApplicationSchema);
};
```

On the front end, in order for a "Broker" to create an "Application," he must first add a "customer" to the application. To do this, a Broker will search for a user by email, and the server can respond with either:

1. email exists (User Object = id, email, ...)
2. No user found ({})

It would not be possible to store an _id in "Create Application" API endpoint, because when a "Broker" creates an "Application", the "customer" is sent a link in their email to register (new _id), and the _id linked to the Application is lost (as far as I know.) I would like my "customer" "dealer" and "broker" to be `String` instead of `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId`, however I would like it to work with .populate('customer dealer broker') using email instead of ID.

Would it make more sense to remove the required validation for name, phone, etc from the User Schema and only require an email for "registration" and request the rest from the "customer" after clicking the confirmation link?

Comment: populating by email is not a good idea (or even possible). If the only problem is the case of "No user found", pass the application id as query parameter in the registration url you're sending in the email. When he signs up through that link, you'll have the application id. You can then both register him and put his _id in `customer`

Comment: You can do it with `Mixed` types, but you in fact would break `.populate()` as mentioned, as well as needing to handle validation a bit more manually. You can still get a "populate like" result, and actually more efficiently with [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) on the server as is demonstrated in the answer here [Mongoose populate either ObjectId reference or String](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44350652/2313887). But it probably might be better to simply create the user and relax the validation in this case.

Comment: `$lookup` is a better option than populate and more efficient. if you want to reference by some other field than _id, then go for `$lookup`. See `aggregation` in `mongodb`, and serch for `$lookup`

Comment: Thank you all for your wonderful suggestions. I decided to go with Talha's approach and just register the application_id with the customer's registration.